# Facebook timeline like listview

Tags: android, facebook, listview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

The Facebook timeline seems to display all the feeds in the listview vertically. When the user shares his/her multiple photos, then those photos are displayed in horizontal list view. Has anybody any idea, how this actually works. Because I don't think nesting a horizontal listview within vertical listview works. Nor does the horizontal listview functions smoothly within the vertical scrollbar. So, if anybody has any idea about how Facebook implements its views in timeline, do share it here.

Comment: I think it is possible to put more listviews into each other... Just implement two custom ArrayAdapters and you can do it...

Comment: It looks to me like a Gallery inside the list item!

Answer (score 0):

To use a gallery for the photos check out that example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11544447/944070

You may also need an implementation of different list items per case, so this answer would also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515221/944070

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using custom list view. Below tutorial covers facebook like feed view using volley networking library

[Android Facebook like Custom ListView Feed using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/)

[image]